# How to update a state after a TextInput change before render in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a text input that is empty until a user has change its value only then the state is changed. The problem with React native is that regardless whether there are values on the states it will continue to render. Here is my code so far.

**First section** the usual react-native code for setting the states

```
export default class Whereto extends Component<{}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            location: null,
            error: null,
            markers:[],
            goingto: '',
        };
    }
```

**Second section** of the code is the componentWillMount section, as i understand it is meant to be use so states can be updated before render, here is my try:

```
componentWillMount(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (pos) => {
                this.setState({
                    latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                    error: null,
                });
                //directions api
                var apiDirectionskey = '';
                const {goingto} = this.state;

                fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + pos.coords.latitude + ',' + pos.coords.longitude + '&destination=' + goingto + '&mode=transit&arrival_time=1391374800&key=' + apiDirectionskey)
                    .then((resdirections) => resdirections.json())
                    .then((responseJson3) => {

                        // noinspection JSAnnotator
                        if (goingto !== '') {
                            console.log(responseJson3);
                        } else {
                            console.log('no-response');
                        }
                    });
```

**Third Section** is my render section, which has my text input
 render(){

```
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Mainlogo/>
                <TextInput style={styles.boxInput} underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' placeholder="Going To?"
                           underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                           onChange={(dest) =>this.setState({goingto : dest})}
                           />
```

... truncated from a much larger code..
    )

```
    }
}
```

I did not include a button, just a textbox that changes state called goingto. I have been modifying the code for hours and still not able to get a response or get results from my fetch call because i need the value of my goingto state as a a parameter in order to complete my fetch call. It remains empty or at least i think it is empty after i input change the TextInput. Any pointers on how this is done properly would be great

console.log() results from the set states.

This result comes up first from my fetch section

```
14:50:46
no-response
```

This result comes from my text input, only accepting single characters

```
Object {
  "goingto": "N",
}
14:50:55
Object {
  "goingto": "O",
}
14:50:55
Object {
  "goingto": "T",
}
14:50:55
Object {
  "goingto": "T",
}
14:50:56
Object {
  "goingto": "I",
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component will only rerender if its state is updated. In the code you provided you have only 2 `setState`: first in your `componentWillMount` and the second in your `TextInput`. The point is to identify which of those are being called many times so it's causing your component to keep rendering.
I think the best way to debug it is adding a console.log to your `setState` callback, this way the log will be printed after the `setState` is finished.

It's important to mention that `componentWillMount` is a sync method Make sure `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` don't need to be async, otherwise, your state can always be empty, since it didn't have enough time to be executed.

If you need `getCurrentPosition` to be async, you must not call it on `componentWillMount`.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: I did your suggestions and included a console log on my set states, I can confirm that the text input is the cause of the rendering. It happens when I input something on my textboox. However, it is printing undefined, on each call

Comment: this comment is an update from my console.log() results.  onChangeText={(dest) => this.setState(console.log({goingto : dest}))}
                               value={this.state.goingto}/>  but it only accepts one character at a time, ive updated my post above, showing the results of the console.log()